# React : callback in eventlistener get old state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a component that adds an eventlistener on `mousedown`, removes the listener on `mouseup` and call parent's callback in `handleMouseup` but if I don't use `useCallback()` and add the parent's callback to deps, the event callback will not update, and the ref will be null.

I'm not sure `useCallback` is the right solution, although it did work
If you don’t mind, could you tell me how to improve my code, thanks.

You can find my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-mountain-ick7e

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();
export default function App() {
  // const ref = React.useRef();
  const [ref, setRef] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ ref }}>
      <div className="App" ref={ref => setRef(ref)}>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Parent />
      </div>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
function Parent(props) {
  const { ref } = React.useContext(AppContext);
  function parentCallback(e) {
    console.log(ref);
  }
  return <Child onChange={parentCallback} />;
}
function Child(props) {
  const btn = React.useRef();
  function onMouseDown(e) {
    props.onChange(e);
    btn.current.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
  }
  // if I don't add onChange to useCllback deps,
  // parent ref in onChange cllback will be null.
  function onMouseUp(e) {
    props.onChange(e);
    btn.current.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
    btn.current.removeEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    btn.current.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
  }, []);

  return <button ref={btn}>click me</button>;
}
```

Comment: what's the benefit of using `ref` instead of defining the handler on react's event system?

Answer (score 0):

What you *could* do is, use the React event system like azium proposed. This would look something like this:

```
function Child({ onMouseDown, onMouseUp }) {
  const handleMouseDown = event => {
    if (onMouseDown) onMouseDown(event);
  };
  const handleMouseUp = event => {
    if (onMouseUp) onMouseUp(event);
  };

  return (
    <button onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}>
      click me
    </button>
  );
}
```

Or like in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-butterfly-6m49f

The react bindings for events exist for pretty much all native events, at least the most commonly used ones.